# CakePHP HABTM relationships and deleting

Tags: cakephp

I'm writing a cake app where I'm trying to model a situation where a group has permissions to services, and users in that group can have a subset of those permissions.  If the group loses permission to a service, the users in that group should also lose permission.

My tables:

```
groups (id), services (id), groups_services (id, service_id, group_id), users (id, group_id), users_services (id, groups_services_id, user_id)
```

Currently, groups has a HABTM relationship with services.  The problem is that if I remove a group from a service, then it should be removed from all users in that group as well.  I know normally with CakePHP you can do this by having a dependent => true defined on your model relationship, but in this case, users_services is dependent on the join table, groups_services, that represents the HABTM, so I don't think this will work.  Will I have to break up the HABTM relationship in order to get this to work, and use instead groups hasMany groups_services and services hasMany group_services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model):

> HABTM data is treated like a complete set, each time a new data
>   association is added the complete set of associated rows in database
>   is dropped and created again so you will always need to pass the whole
>   data set for saving. For an alternative to using HABTM see hasMany
>   through (The Join Model)

So, HABTM is mainly good for pretty 'dumb' relationships.

In most situations where you want any kind of fine-grained control, HABTM isn't a good fit.

So, short answer, yes. Break up your HABTM and use a [has many through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model), as you thought.